# Rendering sprites on a Mali-400 MP device

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d

I started developing a small cross platform game engine using OpenGL, I am working actually on a sprite batch renderer.
Everything is working fine on OS X, iOS, Win32, and some Android Devices. Here is the Results :
[image: screen shot] [image: Mali 400] 
The image on the left show the correct result, and was tested on Samsung galaxy S1, Galaxy J5, Galaxy S3, Galaxy Tab 3.
The device that give these weird results on the right is a Samsung Galaxy Core 2, With a Mali-400 MP renderer.
I start getting that weird result when I use more than one texture.

Here is my Sprite Batch class :

```
Glyph::Glyph(const maths::vec2 &position, const maths::vec2 &dimensions, const maths::vec4 &uvRect, GLuint texture, unsigned int color, float zOrder) :
textureID(texture) {

    a_zOrder = zOrder;

    topLeft.m_color = color;
    topLeft.setPosition(position.x, position.y + dimensions.y);
    topLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);

    bottomLeft.m_color = color;
    bottomLeft.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
    bottomLeft.setUV(uvRect.x, uvRect.y);

    bottomRight.m_color = color;
    bottomRight.setPosition(position.x + dimensions.x, position.y);
    bottomRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y);

    topRight.m_color = color;
    topRight.setPosition(position.x + dimensions.x, position.y + dimensions.y);
    topRight.setUV(uvRect.x + uvRect.z, uvRect.y + uvRect.w);
}


//SpriteBatch
ORendererSpriteBatch::ORendererSpriteBatch(): m_vboID(0), m_vaoID(0)
{
    Init();
}

ORendererSpriteBatch::~ORendererSpriteBatch()
{
    if (m_vboID != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_vboID);
    }

    if (m_vaoID != 0) {
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_vaoID);
    }
}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::Init()
{
    createVertexArray();
}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::Begin()
{
    m_renderBatches.clear();

    // Makes _glpyhs.size() == 0, however it does not free internal memory.
    // So when we later call emplace_back it doesn't need to internally call new.
    m_glyphs.clear();
}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::Submit(const OSprite* renderable)
{
    m_glyphs.emplace_back(renderable->GetPosition(), renderable->GetSize(), renderable->GetUV(), renderable->GetTID(), renderable->GetColor(), renderable->GetZOrder());
}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::End()
{
    // Set up all pointers for fast sorting
    m_glyphPointers.resize(m_glyphs.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_glyphs.size(); i++) {
        m_glyphPointers[i] = &m_glyphs[i];
    }

    sortGlyphs();
    createRenderBatches();
}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::Flush(OLayer2D *layer)
{
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    ORendererFactory::OShader_Simple2D->bind();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    ORendererFactory::OShader_Simple2D->setUniform1i("u_diffuse", 0);
    ORendererFactory::OShader_Simple2D->setUniformMat4("u_MVP", layer->getCamera()->getCameraMatrix());
    glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_renderBatches.size(); i++) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_renderBatches[i].texture);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, m_renderBatches[i].offset, m_renderBatches[i].numVertices);
    }

    ORendererFactory::OShader_Simple2D->unbind();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


void ORendererSpriteBatch::createRenderBatches() {
    // This will store all the vertices that we need to upload
    std::vector <VertexData2D> vertices;
    // Resize the buffer to the exact size we need so we can treat
    // it like an array
    vertices.resize(m_glyphPointers.size() * 6);

    if (m_glyphPointers.empty()) {
        return;
    }

    int offset = 0; // current offset
    int cv = 0; // current vertex

    //Add the first batch
    m_renderBatches.emplace_back(offset, 6, m_glyphPointers[0]->textureID);
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->topLeft;
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->bottomLeft;
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->bottomRight;
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->bottomRight;
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->topRight;
    vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[0]->topLeft;
    offset += 6;

    //Add all the rest of the glyphs
    for (size_t cg = 1; cg < m_glyphPointers.size(); cg++) {

        // Check if this glyph can be part of the current batch
        if (m_glyphPointers[cg]->textureID != m_glyphPointers[cg - 1]->textureID) {
            // Make a new batch
            m_renderBatches.emplace_back(offset, 6, m_glyphPointers[cg]->textureID);
        } else {
            // If its part of the current batch, just increase numVertices
            m_renderBatches.back().numVertices += 6;
        }
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->topLeft;
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->bottomLeft;
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->bottomRight;
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->bottomRight;
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->topRight;
        vertices[cv++] = m_glyphPointers[cg]->topLeft;
        offset += 6;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID);

    // Bind our VBO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboID);
    // Orphan the buffer (for speed)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(VertexData2D), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // Upload the data
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(VertexData2D), vertices.data());

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    // Unbind the VBO
    //        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::createVertexArray() {

    // Generate the VAO if it isn't already generated
    if (m_vaoID == 0) {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vaoID);
    }

    // Bind the VAO. All subsequent opengl calls will modify it's state.
    glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID);

    //G enerate the VBO if it isn't already generated
    if (m_vboID == 0) {
        glGenBuffers(1, &m_vboID);
    }
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboID);

    //Tell opengl what attribute arrays we need
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT,         GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_vertex));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE , sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_color));
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT        , GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_uv));

    glBindVertexArray(0);

}

void ORendererSpriteBatch::sortGlyphs() {

    std::stable_sort(m_glyphPointers.begin(), m_glyphPointers.end(), compareFunction);

}

bool ORendererSpriteBatch::compareFunction(Glyph* a, Glyph* b) {
    if (a->a_zOrder == b->a_zOrder) {
        return (a->textureID < b->textureID);
    }
    return (a->a_zOrder < b->a_zOrder);
}
```

And here is how I call that class :

```
    m_CurrentRenderer->Begin();

    for (const OSprite* renderable : m_Renderables)
        if(m_Camera->isBoxInView(renderable->GetPosition(), renderable->GetSize())){
            renderable->Submit(m_CurrentRenderer);
        }

    m_CurrentRenderer->End();
    m_CurrentRenderer->Flush(this);
```

Any suggestion about what might cause that bug is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT,         GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_vertex));
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE , sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_color));
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT        , GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexData2D), (void *)offsetof(VertexData2D, m_uv));
```

Assumes that the vertex position is attribute #0, colour is attribute #1 and uv is attribute #2.

Do you enforce that in any way? Declaring the attributes in that order in your vertex shader doesn't guarantee that the attributes will take on that order.

You can specify the attribute locations using glBindAttribLocation prior to linking the program, or you can use glGetAttribLocation to query the location instead.

Comment: Yes I am already enforcing that using glBindAttribLocation. otherwise this wouldn't work on any OpenGL ES device. As I mentioned, It work on most devices except for that one,  If all my sprites uses the same texture, the sprite batch works. but when I use more than one texture, it gives me these weird results

Comment: Aha - so it only happens when there's an offset in glDrawArrays - it could be a driver bug. I had a weird glitch on one device with a Mali-400 (a Tesco Hudl), which I believe was the same one described here: https://community.arm.com/message/19003. Annoyingly, ARM are not in the habit of including a build number in their GL_VERSION string so it isn't straightforward to figure out if you're possibly affected.



In the end I didn't find a workaround as the glitch was short-lived in my application. If you're able to update the driver on that device then that might be worth trying.

Comment: So there is no workaround to fix this ? except updating the driver ?

Comment: There might be a workaround, but I didn't bother trying because for me the glitch only lasted for about a second then rendering returned to normal, so I decided I could live with it. 
There's no guarantee that the issue I saw is related to the one in the link or to your one either.